# How to mimick Oracle Materialized Views on MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, view

Application connected to MS SQL Server will create views where a single row result is an analysis including aggregations of 1-10k records. The applicable criteria across the resulting view will have dozens to tens of thousands of results. The view+criteria will then be ordered by some column (user specified) in the view which are most likely to be the aggregated columns. Response times are expected to degrade quickly when aggregated column is used for ordering.

A while back, this problem was solved pretty easily (in Oracle 9i) with materialized views. 
Any ideas on how to get a similar solution in MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use Indexed views for this.

Read here for SQL 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx

Read here for SQL 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx

Comment: +1 for Indexed Views, alternative would be Analysis services but IX Views are the equvalent to materialised views.

Comment: There is no support for OUTER Joins. So it isn't a full replacement.

Answer (score 5):

Materialized views are not same as indexed views. MS SQL server indexed views have multiple limitations such as use of outer joins, aggregates and common table expressions.

Comment: not same, but nevertheless they are the closest thing to them