# Most efficient way to store queries and counts of large SQL data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database with a large amount of data (65 million rows mostly of text, 8Gb total). The data gets changed only once per week. I have an ASP.NET web application that will run several SQL queries on this data that will count the number of rows satisfying various conditions. Since the data gets changed only once per week, what is the most efficient way to store both the SQL queries and their counts for the week? Should I store it in the database or in the application?

Comment: BTW, 65 million rows and 8GB total is not really that large...

Comment: Does MS SQL Server support materialized views? That would be an idea. (I did a quick search and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527141/how-to-mimick-oracle-materialized-views-on-ms-sql-server).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is only modified once a week, as part of and at the end of that (ETL?) process, perform your "basic" counts and store the results in a table in the database. Thereafter, rather than lengthy queries on the big tables, you can just query those small summary tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need 100% up-to-the-minute accurate row counts, you could query SQL Server's internal info:

```
Select so.name as 'TableName', si.rowcnt as 'RowCount'
from sysobjects so
inner join sysindexes si on so.id = si.id 
where so.type = 'u' and indid < 2
```

Very quick to execute and no extra tables required.  Not accurate where many updates are occurring but *might* be accurate enough in your intended usage. [Thank you to commenters!]

**Update**: did a bit of digging and this does produce accurate counts (slower due to the sum, but still quick):

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(ps.object_id) AS SchemaName, 
       OBJECT_NAME(ps.object_id) AS ObjectName, 
       SUM(ps.row_count) AS row_count
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = ps.object_id
                      AND i.index_id = ps.index_id
WHERE i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED','HEAP')
AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(ps.object_id) <> 'sys'
GROUP BY ps.object_id
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(ps.object_id), OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(ps.object_id)
```

[Ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2010/04/02/dmv-series-sys-dm-db-partition-stats.aspx).

> Remember that the stored count information was not always 100%
>   accurate in SQL Server 2000. For a new table created on 2005 the
>   counts will be accurate. But for a table that existed in 2000 and now
>   resides on 2005 through a restore or update, you need to run (only
>   once after the move to 2005) either sp_spaceused @updateusage =
>   N'true' or DBCC UPDATEUSAGE with the COUNT_ROWS option.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that the results of these queries are always 100% accurate, even though I use them myself. Is there proof positive on this, one way or the other?

Comment: Metadata rowcounts are not 100% accurate if there are frequent changes.  For  the OP's situation (weekly updates) it's unlikely they won't be accurate though.

Comment: @mitch - sysindexes is only as accurate as the current stats.

Comment: @mitch - me too.  I've read it from multiple OTHER sources, just not from MSDN.  We need someone like Remus to come by and confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

The queries should be stored as stored procedures or views, depending on complexity.

For your situation I would look into [indexed views.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

They let you both store a query AND the result set for things like aggregation that otherwise cannot be indexed.

As a bonus, the query optimizer "knows" it has this data as well, so if you check for a count or something else stored in the view index in another query (even one not referencing the view directly) it can still use that stored data.

Comment: Indexed views can be very useful, but I think they are overkill in this situation.

Comment: @Mitch - maybe.  He doesn't say how often he needs to check these aggregates or how many there are, or how much query activity there is on the results.