# How to cache a query which is often used?

Tags: sql-server, performance, jakarta-ee, content-management-system

When there is a web app will query some information frequently, how to improve the performance by cache the query result?
(The information is like top news in a website and my database is SQL Server 2008, the application is on tomcat.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest the following:

1. In your database you can use idex views, please check:  [How to mimick Oracle Materialized Views on MS SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527141/how-to-mimick-oracle-materialized-views-on-ms-sql-server).
2. If you has used JPA or Hibernate it can cache Entities (objects).

   - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache
   - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching
3. If you're looking for a cache system that is foreign to database and ORM, maybe you can review MemCache or EHCache.

   - http://memcached.org/
   - http://ehcache.org/
4. An option but not recommended is that you manage a cache in your application, by example you can store at ServletContext (also know as ApplicationContext) the list of Countries, but you need to implement the business logic for cache (update, delete and insert objects), also you need to be careful with the Heap Memory.

You can use a combination of the above strategies it depends of the context of your business

Best regards,

Ernesto.

Comment: + wrap the query to the materialized view into a sproc and use CallableStatement and statement caching when working with JDBC.

Comment: @bobah why does procedure can improve the performance?

Comment: @newand - the query will be constantly precompiled on server

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty general question and as you'd expxect, there are many options.

Closest to the UI, your web platform might have 'content caching.' ASP.NET, for example, will cache portions of a page for specified periods of time.

You could use a caching tool like memcached and cache a recordset (or whatever the stand-alone Java data structure is).

Some ORM's provide caching too.

And (probably not finally) you could define structure in your database to 'cache' results like this by running complex queries and saving the results into tables that are queried more often but are cheaper to query.

Just some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, is there any advice on the using of  SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for a really big site is all of the above.  We do all our queries via stored procs.  That helps because the query is compiled and one execution plan is reused.  We have a wicked ccomplicated table valued function.  It's so expensive we built a cache table.  The table has the same general foormat as the function but with two extras.  One is an expire time.  The other is a search key.  The search key is the parameters that go into the function concatenated together.  Whenever we're about to query that table we run a Proc to check if the data is stale.  If it is we start a transaction delete the rows, and then run the function and insert the rows.  This means we run the function maybe 2 or 3% of the times we used to and the proc call we make to check for staleness is much cheaper.  Whenever the app updates the relevant data it goes and updates the cache rows as stale - but it doesn't delete them we leave that to the cache check function.  Why?  Well maybe nobody will need that data right now, so less db hit.  Then we hit the second layer.  We cache many recordsets in memcached.  Including all of the procs that call that function, and many more.  That actually happens in our asp layer, which we still have.  ADO recordsets can be persisted to xml natively, which then goes into memcache as a string.